Webtransport example for android in kotlin
As far as I know, Webtransport is already available in Android and chrome is already using it.
The problem is that I can't find any example about how to use it in kotlin or even java.
I want to use datagram or streams to create bidirectional communication with my webtransport server.
Thank you in advance for your help.

"Webtransport is already available in Android" -- WebTransport is a Web API. It is not part of an operating system. "I can't find any example about how to use it in kotlin or even java" -- asking for off-site resources is off-topic for Stack Overflow. It feels like your best hope is to see if Cronet supports it.
